# Twitter Sentimental Analysis with Datumbox in R: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, api, loops, twitter, datumbox

I'm new to Twitter Sentimental Analysis with Datumbos in R, and I was trying to run the following code,

```
tweets = searchTwitter("House of Cards", n=1500, lang="en")
tweet_txt = sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())

tweet_clean = clean.text(tweet_txt)

tweet_num = length(tweet_clean)
# data frame (text, sentiment)
# data frame (text, sentiment, score)
tweet_df = data.frame(text=tweet_clean, sentiment=rep("", tweet_num),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

sentiment = rep(0, tweet_num)
for (i in 1:tweet_num)
{
tmp = getSentiment(tweet_clean[i], "API Key")
tweet_df$sentiment[i] = tmp$sentiment
}
```

Then I receive the error as below,

> Error in tweet_df$sentiment[i] = tmp$sentiment : 
>     replacement has length zero

I can't figure out what went wrong, and tried to run to following code to check

```
str(tweet_df)
```

> 'data.frame': 1500 obs. of  5 variables:...

```
str(tweet_clean)
```

> chr [1:1500] "tx for following read the opening chapters of the dotty series" ...

```
str(tweet_num)
```

> int 1500

Comment: the problems seems to be in `getSentiment()`, did you check it?

Comment: @mabdrabo aw thanks so much! Turned out something was wrong with my API key but somehow it went through

Comment: good. glad to help